# CodeNameOne , reading JSON without root

Tags: java, json, list, dictionary, codenameone

I usually cast map to list to read JSON 
but in this case i haven't "root" . What should i do ?
this is the code that i use to read Json using root :

```
   Map<String, Object> p = j.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader(json.toCharArray()));
   List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) p.get("root");
```

JSON with root :

> > {root=[{nom=ayoub, prenom=Mlaouah, cin=1.344444444E9, datenaissance={timezone={name=Europ............

JSON without root:

> > {id=1.0, idAgee={nom=ayoub, prenom=Mlaouah, cin=1.344444444E9,.......

Comment: check if `p` has `"root"` then either use `p.get("root")` or `p` directly in your existing code

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: oh yes, the second json example you have is NOT a list, it is a map

Comment: so how can i read Json ? i need to convert it to list to be able to do loop (for) and read data .. can you advice me a solution ?

Comment: read it as a map, instead of list and loop through map keys

Comment: Ok thank you :) ,  .. if you can write me simple code to understand your solution .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root is a trick we add to parse JSON arrays. Without the root you just get the map and can start querying the JSON e.g.:

```
Map m = (Map)p.get("idAgee");
```

Root is there if the JSON is an array to begin with. Since the method return signature is a `Map` and not `List` we can't return a `List` so we wrap the response with a `Map` containing `root`.